# How to bind object as a json string to another html element on JQUERY Template plugin

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-templates

Actually i tried to find it but i was lost in plug-in lines while debugging.
I want to show how it is working because there are different template plug-ins.

```
$("#teplateScript").tmpl(arrOfWhatWeWantToBind).appendTo("#divElementwhichWillContainTheOutput");
```

I want to serialize every element of array(to json of course) with `JSON.stringify` and set the hidden element in the template. If i serialize object and add the output to the same object with another property, i could access it but i want to do this in the template like:

```
<script type="text/html">
   <div>$(propOfElement)</div>
   <input type="hidden" id="hdnObj_${idOfElement)" value="JSON.stringif( ?.....? )" />
</script>
```

What should i write to instead of `?....?` place ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/html">
   <div>$(propOfElement)</div>
   <input type="hidden" id="hdnObj_${idOfElement)" value="${ JSON.stringify($data) }" />
</script>
```